# Monotonicity of a probability sequence

Tags: probability, measure-theory, probability-theory

Let $\mathbb{P}$ be a probability measure on $\mathbb{R}^n$, so $\mathbb{P}( \mathbb{R}^n ) = 1$.

Consider a mapping $f: \mathcal{P}( \mathbb{R}^n ) \rightarrow \{ 0, 1, ..., F \}$, where $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ denotes the power set of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $F \in \mathbb{Z}_{>0}$. Denote by $\mathbb{P}^N$ the product measure $\mathbb{P} \times \mathbb{P} \times ... \times \mathbb{P}$ ($N$ times).

Define 
$$\bar{f}_N := {\text{ess}\sup}_{ (x_1, ..., x_N) \in (\mathbb{R}^n)^N } \ f( \{ x_1, ..., x_N \} ) \in \{ 0, 1, 2, ..., F \}, $$
where $\text{ess}\sup$ denotes the [essential supremum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Essential_supremum_and_essential_infimum).

Assume that $\bar{f}_N = \bar{f}_M =: \bar{f}$ for all $N, M \geq n$.

I am wondering if for all $N \geq n$ it then holds:
$$ \mathbb{P}^{N+1}\left( \left\{ (x_1, ..., x_{N+1}) \in (\mathbb{R}^n)^{N+1} \mid f( \{ x_1, ..., x_{N+1} \} ) \geq \bar{f} \right\} \right) \geq \mathbb{P}^{N}\left( \left\{ (x_1, ..., x_{N}) \in (\mathbb{R}^n)^N \mid f( \{ x_1, ..., x_{N} \} ) \geq \bar{f} \right\} \right) $$

Comment. I assume that all the probability integrals are well defined.

Comment: I added a simplifying assumption: $\bar{f} = \bar{f}_N$ for all $N$.

Comment: When $f$ is a map on the power set of $\mathbb{R}^n$, what does it mean for it to be measurable? What is the measure on $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}^n)$?

Comment: Good question. I just mean that the probability integral $P^N[ f\{ (x_1, ..., x_N) \geq \bar{f} \} ]$ is well defined.

Comment: As already mentioned on a recent very related question: "Without more assumptions on f, this is doomed."

Comment: Can you please provide an example where this claim holds, and another example where it does not hold?

Comment: Should I additionally assume that $f$ does not depend on the cardinality (finite or infinite) of the argument set?

Comment: A similar question is posted here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/588004/probability-of-a-sequence-with-max