# Probability of convergence of a monotone sequence

Tags: probability, measure-theory, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $\left(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P} \right)$ be a [probability space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_space), and let $X: \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ be a [random variable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_variable). Let $\mathbb{P}^N$ denote the product measure $\mathbb{P} \times \mathbb{P} \times ... \times \mathbb{P}$ ($N$ times).

Consider a function $f: \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}^n) \rightarrow \{0, 1, \ldots, F\}$, where $F \in \mathbb{Z}_{>0}$, and $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is the [power set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set) of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Assume that $f(A) \geq f(B)$ if $A \supseteq B$.

For randomly extracted $\omega_1$, $\omega_2$, ..., consider the sequence: 
$$g_1 := f(\{ X(\omega_1) \} ) \\ 
g_2 := f(\{ X(\omega_1), \ X(\omega_2) \} ) \\ \vdots \\
g_{i}:= f( \{ X(\omega_1), ..., \ X(\omega_{i}) \} )$$

By construction, the sequence $\{g_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ is non-decreasing and uniformly bounded, therefore $\lim_{i \rightarrow \infty } g_i = \bar{g} \in \{0,1,...,F\}$.

Question. What kind of probabilistic claims can be made about $g_i$? That is to say, is it possible to upper bound the quantity
$$ \mathbb{P}^N\left(\left\{ (\omega_1, ..., \omega_N) \in \Omega^N \mid g_N = g_N(\omega_1, ..., \omega_N) = \bar{g} \right\}\right) $$
by a decreasing function of $N$?

Comment: I think the Kolmogorov 0-1 law applies, via a detour through Polish spaces.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Looking in [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov's_zero%E2%80%93one_law] I was not able to get the meaning of your comment. Can you please explain? Thanks a lot.